# how can i prove that $\frac{e^{n}}{n^{2}}>n$ for $n>4$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function

I would like to prove that $$\frac{e^{n}}{n^{2}}>n$$ for $n > 4$?

This can't be proved by induction since $1$ satisfies the inequality but $3$ does not because $$\frac{e^{3}}{3^{2}} - 3  < 1$$

Comment: It *can* be proved by induction, starting at $n=5$ for the base case.

Comment: It asks to prove it for $n > 4$. You don't have to consider $n \le 4$ for the proof.

Comment: ok. I said that this can't  be proved by induction because i tought that if a i can make the inductive step, then i only need a base case (like mostly of the proof by induction that i have made before). But in this proof i need the base case to make the inductive step.

Comment: Your base case should be $n=5$.

Comment: " But in this proof i need the base case to make the inductive step. "  It doesn't matter whether you make a base case first or an induction case first.  And it doesn't matter for this proof either.

Comment: well, if I can make the induction case without using the base case, then this would true for n =2 since is true for n = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac {e^n}{n^2} > n \iff$

$e^n > n^3$

Base case: $n = 5$.  $e^5 > 5^3$ .... because it is.  It's just  one case and enter it into a calculator.  It is true.

Induction:  If $e^n > n^3$ then $e^{n+1} = e*e^n$ and $(n+1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$  as $n \ge 5$ then $n >1$, $4n < n^2$ and $54n^2 \le n^3$ so $(n+1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 <n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + n = n^3 + 3n^2 + 4n < n^3 + 3n^2 + n^2 = n^3 + 4n^2 < n^3 + n^3 = 2n^3 < 2*e^n < e*e^n = e^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $n$, the inequality is equivalent to $\displaystyle\frac{e^n}{n^3}>1$. Since $f(n)=\displaystyle\frac{e^n}{n^3}$ is an increasing function in the relevant domain (just check $f'(n)$), we only need to show that the inequality holds for $n=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^x-x^3$.

Thus, $$f'''(x)=e^x-6>0$$ for all $x>4$, which says that $f''$ is an increasing function.

Thus, $$f''(x)>f''(4)=e^4-6\cdot4>0,$$ which says that $f'$ is an increasing function.

Thus, $$f'(x)>f'(4)=e^4-3\cdot4^2>0, $$ which says that $f$ increases.

Id est, $$f(x)\geq f(5)=e^5-5^3>0$$ and we are done!

Comment: The tag said pre-calculus.

Comment: @fleablood If so, what is it $e$?

Comment: It’s a number that is introduced in most precalculus classes 

Comment: 2.71 something.  You do have a point.  But many precalculus classes teach exponents and logarithms of arbitrary bases and using the concept of "compound interest" the idea of $(1+\frac an)^n $ and that $e=\lim (1+\frac 1n)^n $.  Or simply that e is a number, like pi, that is important because the teacher said it was important.

Answer (score 0):

You can so it with induction, start by checking for $n=5$ and do the following:

Assuming it is true for $n$:
$$\frac{e^{n}}{n^{2}}>n\implies \frac{e^{n}}{n^{2}}\times \frac{en^2}{(n+1)^2}>n\times \frac{en^2}{(n+1)^2}\implies \frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2}}>n\times \frac{en^2}{(n+1)^2}\implies e^n\times \frac{e}{(n+1)^{2}}<n^3\times \frac{e}{(n+1)^{2}}$$
Now you need to prove that $e^n>n^3$ for $n>4$. You can do it in a lot of ways, for example showing that $e>\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}$ for all $n>4$(this is true for all $n>\frac{1}{e^{\frac13}-1}$ but it doesn't really matters). You can do this because $e^n\times e=e^{n+1}$ and $n^3\times \frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}=(n+1)^3$ thus we get $e^{n+1}>(n+1)^3$ which implies $\frac{e^{n}}{n^{2}}>n$ for all $n>4$.